# Xpath expression in Android for node with two child text nodes

Tags: android, xpath, htmlcleaner

I have a sample XML (Android platform) and I wanted to know the easiest and most efficient approach to get the node value of the text node.

```
<div id="myid">
   <img src="..." width="1" height="2" alt="Text" />
   <p><strong>Unwanted text</strong>WANTED TEXT</p>
</div>
```

I can get it easily with XPath 2.0 as:

```
//div[@id='myid']//p/text() => WANTED TEXT
```

but in Android I'm getting ...

```
//div[@id='myid']//p/text() => Unwanted text&nbsp;WANTED TEXT
```

but how can i select this in Android's XPath without the unwanted text?

Comment: Finally, I retrieved the parent node and navigate to the node programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure Android is behaving as expected here. However, try these two statements to see if they return the desired results instead.

Get the first node which is not an element:

```
//div[@id='myid']//p/node()[not(self::*)]
```

Get the first node which is a text node:

```
//div[@id='myid']//p/node()[self::text()]
```

(Note that I haven't been able to test these on Android, so I can't say for certain what they will return).

Comment: Thnx for your comment Tim, but node() is not supported.